# How to save the SQL Server table xml column data in physical path as .xml format?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have an sql server database table which has xml column name called "MESSAGE" and which will store xml data.

The database table look like,

[image]

Now I need to get this "**MESSAGE**" column data and save into System physical path as xml file(Ex: test.xml etc.,)

Any suggestion how to implement this using c#.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (using plain ADO.NET and a very basic SQL query):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get connection string from app./web.config
        string connectionString = "server=.;database=yourDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        // define query
        string query = "SELECT MESSAGE FROM dbo.SamTest WHERE ID = 1;";

        // set up connection and command
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            // open connection, execute query to get XML, close connection
            conn.Open();
            string xmlContents = selectCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            conn.Close();

            // define target file name
            string targetFileName = @"C:\tmp\test.xml";

            // write XML out to file
            File.WriteAllText(targetFileName, xmlContents);
        }
    }
```